# Unable to import previously working SAS-formats files using R-package 'haven'

Tags: r, sas, format, r-haven

Around a year ago, I used the 'haven'-package to import two .sas7bdat files along with their respective .sas7bcat formats and it worked wonderfully.

For some reason, however, it does not any longer even though all the SAS-files incl. format files have remained unchanged since then.

When I try running the code now, R gives me the following error:

> ```
> Error in df_parse_sas_file(spec_data, spec_cat, encoding = encoding,
>   catalog_encoding = catalog_encoding,  :    Failed to parse P:/SAS
>   files/formats.sas7bcat: Invalid file, or file has unsupported features.
> ```

R and the 'haven'-package have been reinstalled to their newest versions since the first time when it worked, so I imagine that this might be the reason since all the SAS-files and the code remains unchanged.

For this reason, I tried to reinstall the old version of 'haven' but cannot since this apparently requires a manual installation of 'Rtools' which is not allowed on my computer, so I am a bit stuck here.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you can find the package you can do a manual installation after downloading it. Not simple but not super difficult either.

Answer (score 0):

A potential workaround is that the package sas7bdat can also read SAS files. I don't know how much extra work this might involve for you though

You can read in a dataset with the code

> read.sas7bdat("filename.sas7bdat")